# Matlab launcher not found windows 8

Tags: windows-8, installation, matlab

I recently installed matlab in windows 8, in a different drive, other than the program files. After installation, its strange but am not able to find any launcher icon. Be it for uninstallation, or even for starting matlab. Can you please tell me what the issue is? I am sorry if the question is very rudimentary, but your help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you get to the installation directory and run Matlab from that? If so, don't worry much about it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the lacking of the icon does not need to indicate a problem.

Just go to the place where MATLAB has been installed, and create a new icon upon finding the executable there.